# Service to generate trackable URLs

Tags: url, analytics, qr-code

I'm looking for a url tracking service where I can generate urls (for which I can make QR codes) and later I would need to edit the redirect URL. So the problem is, currently I don't have the final URLs, but the QR codes needs to be created, so I would need URLs like ex: *www.awesometracking.com/**sj9Uf*** and later when I have the final URL for my site, in the tools admin area, I can set for the **sj9Uf** id, the target link.

Maybe I'm missing the right keywords, but I cannot find anything, so any idea will help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I found one, which seems to be good: http://yourls.org/
I will test it out, but I'm still curious about other possibilities.

Comment: Test passed. This is a nice little tool.